# Node below axis annotation in tikzpicture/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, arrows, node-connections

I want below the axis annotation a node (with some text) and from this node a arrow should point to a specific point on the x-axis

MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xlabel={x},ylabel={y},grid, width=14cm, xmin=0, xmax=4.55e-3, ymin=0, ymax=1]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}%
\label{fig:a}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

what i want:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={x},ylabel={y},grid, width=14cm, xmin=0, xmax=4.55e-3, ymin=0, ymax=1]
    \end{axis}
    \node[below right=1cm, font=\Large\bf] (T) {Hello text};
    \draw[thick, -latex] (T.west) to[bend left] (0,-5mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]